# Unable to import custom swift plugin in Telerik appbuilder

Tags: ios, cordova, telerik

I've written a custom apache cordova plugin in swift for iOS platform and wants to import it in a hybrid appbuilder app but I'm keep getting following error:

> Build errors: [ '[xcode-build] Check dependencies: Swift is unavailable on iOS earlier than 7.0; please set IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to 7.0 or later (currently it is \'6.0\').',
>
> Build failed with error code 2

Its evident from the error message that I need to change the IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to 7.0 or later but unable to find it how could I change it ?

Note: I'm using Sublime Text 2 with appbuilder (version:2.10.0-470) plugin installed on MacBook pro(OSX:10.10.3).

Comment: Are you using Cordova 3.7+? It's needed to do an iOS 8 build in AppBuilder. If you are using Cordova 3.7+ the best place to log this issue is at http://www.telerik.com/forums/appbuilder.

Comment: @TJVanToll Yes I'm using Cordova 5.1.1.

Comment: AppBuilder doesn't support that version directly. What is your “ FrameworkVersion” set to in your .abproject? Also if you're not having any luck here you might want to try posting in the AppBuilder forums: http://www.telerik.com/forums/appbuilder.

Answer (score 0):

To set the iOS deployment target (in this case iOS 7), you need to go into your app's `.abproject` file and add `"iOSDeploymentTarget": “7.0”`.

Example:

```
{
  "ProjectName": "Foo",
  "projectVersion": 1,
  "AppIdentifier": "com.foo.Foo",
  "DisplayName": "Foo",
  "Author": "Evan Wieland",
  "iOSDeploymentTarget": “7.0”
  ...
}
```